# Plucker embedding and tautological/universal quotient bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, grassmannians

Let $G$ be a Grassmannian and $Q$ the tautological/universal quotient bundle of $G$. As far as I understand, the associated tautological quotient line bundle for the Plucker embedding of the Grassmannian $G$ is $\mathrm{det} Q$ and is isomorphic to the pullback of the very ample line bundle of the projective space (in which the Grassmannian is embedded). However, I could not find a reference where this is explained nicely. Could someone suggest a good reference for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your claim descends directly from the definition of the Plucker embedding.

Let $G(n,h)$ be the Grassmannian parametrizing $h$-linear subspaces of $\mathbb{P}^n = \mathbb{P}(V)$. The fiber of the universal bundle $\mathcal{S}$ over $[L]\in G(n,h)$ is the vector space $W$, where $L = \mathbb{P}(W)$.

Now, the Plucker embedding $p:G(h,n)\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^N$ is intrinsically defined mapping $W\mapsto\bigwedge^{h+1}W$. Therefore, $p^{*}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^N}(1)$ 
is a line bundle on $G(h,n)$ whose fiber over $[L]\in G(n,h)$ is the vector space $\bigwedge^{h+1}W$, where $L = \mathbb{P}(W)$, that is 
$$p^{*}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^N}(1)= \bigwedge^{h+1}\mathcal{S}.$$

Comment: Don't you need to take the dual of $\mathcal{S}$?

Answer (score 2):

Everything you've said sounds right, so I think you would be on track to work out the details on your own.  One place I found with a quick Google is [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=6_DU67M3_PgC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=plucker+embedding+line+bundle&source=bl&ots=CPguTvsJ-A&sig=hXftErLREmKDnWceHwgY0wH080I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=T233U7jnJsqoyASjsYDAAQ&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=plucker%20embedding%20line%20bundle&f=false) of Tevelev.  There's also a reasonable discussion in these [notes of Brion](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~mbrion/lecturesrev.ps).